# Finding transfer function in a balance state

Tags: control-system, differential

I have an ODE that looks like this:

$$
   \dfrac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} + 2\sin{y(t)} = u(t) 
$$

Taking u as input and y as output, considering the balance state with

$$
  u(t) = \bar{u}, y(t) = \bar{y}
$$

Now, with

$$
  \bar{y} = \dfrac{π}{2}
$$

Taking the small difference between input and output as

$$
  \delta{u(t)}, \text{ and } \delta{y(t)}
$$

I would like to linearize the ODE and find its transfer function.  Yet, I have not come up with an idea for this problem. What does the small difference mean when reaching the balance (equilibrium) state?

Answer (score 0):

Linearizing a system around a given operating point is a common task in classical control system design and analysis. Let us assume that the behaviour of the system is captured by the following differential equation
$$ \dot{\vec{x}}(t) = \vec{f}(\vec{x}(t), \vec{u}(t))$$
where \$\vec{x}\$ and \$\vec{u}\$ describe the state and control vector respectively. We call \$\vec{x} = \vec{x}_{eq}\$ an equilibrium point of the given system iff
$$\dot{\vec{x}} = 0 = \vec{f}(\vec{x}_{eq}, \vec{u}_{eq})$$
for constant excitation \$\vec{u} = \vec{u}_{eq} \$ and initial condition \$\vec{x}_{0} = \vec{x}_{eq}\$. Exampels would be the (stable) lower or (unstable) upper equilibrium point of a rigid pendulum. It is obvious that our system does not deviate from \$\vec{x}_{eq}\$ as long as our excitation/control action does not deviate from \$\vec{u}_{eq}\$. But what happens if it does? Lets introduce the (small) deviations \$\delta x\$ and \$\delta u\$ from the constant equilibrium values (I am going to drop the vector notation for simplicity but you should keep in mind that the quantities in question are still vector valued in general). In that case our state vector and control signal are given by
$$ x = x_{eq} + \delta x$$
$$ u = u_{eq} + \delta u.$$
Substituting those expressions back into the system equations and performing a taylor expansion of \$f(...)\$ around the equilibrium point \$(x_{eq}, u_{eq})\$ leads to
$$ \dot{x_{eq}} + \dot{\delta x} \approx f(x_{eq}, u_{eq}) + (\partial_{x}f)(x_{eq}, u_{eq})\cdot \delta x + (\partial_{u}f)(x_{eq}, u_{eq}) \cdot \delta u$$
by neglecting all higher order deviation terms due to them being small (likely enforced by the implemented controller). The approximation can be further simplified by crossing out all terms which are zero. We finally arrive at the linearized state equations
$$ \dot{\delta x} = (\partial_{x}f)(x_{eq}, u_{eq})\cdot \delta x + (\partial_{u}f)(x_{eq}, u_{eq}) \cdot \delta u$$
which describes the relation between state and control deviations from the quilibrium point. The linearized equation can be laplace transformed and used for determining the transfer function from \$\delta \underline{U}(\underline{s})\$ to \$\delta \underline{X}(\underline{s})\$.

What steps do you need to solve your problem?

1.) Determine the operating/equilibrium point by setting all derivatives to zero and solve the equation for \$u_{eq}\$ for a given \$y_{eq}\$.

2.) Substitute \$y = y_{eq} + \delta y\$ etc. into the orignal ODE and approximate all nonlinear terms via a taylor expansion around the equilibrium values. Neglect all higher order deviations like \$\delta x \cdot \delta u\$, \$(\delta u)^2\$ etc. The resultant equation is the linearized euqation we searched for.

3.) Perform a Laplace transform of the linearized equation and proceed as usual.

The given explanation can be found in many introductory texts on control theory and automation.